# CI connect to oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, codeigniter

I have database.php in connection from CI

```
$dbhost = '192.168.1.3';    //IP or server name of my host database
$dbport = '1521';    //Oracle port
$dbname = 'dev';    //TNS Name
$dbConnString = "
  (DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS_LIST =   (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = ". $dbhost .")(PORT = ". $dbport .")))
  (CONNECT_DATA =(SERVICE_NAME = ". $dbname .") ))";


$db['default']['hostname'] = $dbConnString;
$db['default']['username'] = 'abc';
$db['default']['password'] = 'abcpass';
$db['default']['database'] = '';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'oci8';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;//FALSE
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;//FALSE
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

But if i run this program always shown error

```
A Database Error Occurred

Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.

Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\reset\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 124
```

What should i do?
oci8 in php.ini already opened

Comment: Did you already run your mysql server?

Comment: @JesusErwinSuarez yeah, mysql server alrd running
i have 3 connection on this apps, 2 on mysql and 1 on oracle and only on oracle i have problem, if i disable db_debug on oracle connection, the application running well but cant query to oracle database

Comment: Do you have SSH access on that CI server? Try telnet to the MySQL server on that server, to make sure the network connection is fine.

Comment: @Raptor its no problem with mysql connection, its just problem on my oracle connection.

Comment: Sorry, I mean oracle connection: Try `telnet 192.168.1.3 1521` on that CI server.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change **default** to **dev** ... your code will be

```
$db['dev']['hostname'] = $dbConnString;
$db['dev']['username'] = 'abc';
$db['dev']['password'] = 'abcpass';
$db['dev']['database'] = '';
.
.
.
```

Comment: yes, oracle instant client alrd installed on server